# Kohana is not loading the result rows?

Tags: php, sql, orm, kohana

if i try to load a result with Kohana ORM, the query is correct, but the result is empty. If i copy the Query and use it in phpmyadmin, i receive 2 rows.

This is the Kohana Code (ORM)

```
        // DB work
        $ftps = ORM::factory('ftp');

        // if we activate many (we load only ready)
        if ($this->request->param('mode') == 'activate') {
            $ftps->where('ready', '=', '1');

        // if we activate many (we load only ready)
        } elseif ($this->request->param('mode') == 'not_ready') {
            $ftps->where('ready', '=', '0');
        }

        // DB work
        $ftps->and_where('activated', '=', '0')
             ->order_by('lastcheck', 'ASC')
             ->limit(intval($post['number']))
             ->find_all();
```

This is the SQL Query (Debug)

```
SELECT `ftp`.* FROM `ftps` AS `ftp` WHERE `activated` = '0' ORDER BY `lastcheck` ASC LIMIT 100 (1)
```

Why is Kohana not able to load the same results like phpmyadmin does? It's the same query. I don't find a solution.

Thank you for your help

Comment: How are you checking if it returns results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem I used to encounter a lot when I was using Kohana. There is a simple but not-that-intuitive explanation to your problem. If you are simply doing...

```
$ftps->find_all();
```

and then try to use `$ftp` as your results set, that won't work, because the `find_all()` function only *returns* the results set, and the `$ftps` query object is being reset. Instead, you need to do...

```
$ftps = $ftps->find_all();
```

and *then* `$ftps` will contain the results set.

Hope that helps!